# Lots Of Extra Null Bytes When Sending File Through TCP

Tags: c#

I've been learning how to use TcpClients in C# for the past few days, and was able to send strings(messages) over tcp. Today, I decided to try and send a a text file(i.e, the client would receive the file and write it to the same folder). It worked, except for one problem - there are a TON of null bytes after the message. Here is what I mean:

Original text file contents: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9up8.png

Received text file contents: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr5Bh.png

I looked at the size of the received file, and the length was 65536 characters. I know the max size of a TCP packet is 65535, so what I'm thinking is something in my code is causing it to use the max size of the packet instead of only the amount it needs.

Here is my code from the server, which sends the file to the client:

```
        if(message.Contains("getFile"))
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("text.txt");
            stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        }
```

Here is my code for the client, which receives the file from the server and writes it to the disk:

```
        if(command.Contains("getFile"))
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int data = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
            File.WriteAllBytes("file.txt", readBuffer);
        }
```

Comment: its not about tcp at all I think, how big is your `client.ReceiveBufferSize` ? you will write as many bytes to your file

Comment: The client.RecieveBufferSize should be set the same as the length of the file if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are completely ignoring the amount of data you got from network, even if you skip network and just do:

```
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
File.WriteAllBytes("file.txt", readBuffer);
```

you will end up with file with a bunch of zeros.

You need to take into account the return value of `stream.Read`:

```
using (BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("file.txt", FileMode.Create)))
{
   binWriter.Write(readBuffer, 0, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it - but would you be able explain how I'm "completely ignoring the amonut of data you got from network"? I'm a bit confused what you mean

Comment: sure, `stream.Read` returns the number of bytes it read from network, but you never used that number. Regardless of how many bytes you really received you were still calling `WriteAllBytes` that writes as many as there in the buffer you have allocated. Thats why I was asking you about the size of the buffer, where did you get `client.ReceiveBufferSize` this?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see what you mean - I did nothing with the 'data' variable.  I suppose File.WriteAllBytes wouldn't be good for this situation.

Comment: well, i showed in my snipped what to do with it - you only need to write `data` bytes to file , not fUll buffer size, buffer could be much much bigger than what you get from network

Comment: Got it. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hey, do any of you guys know if it's possible to do this using File.WriteAllBytes? I read that it's more efficient than BinaryWriter.

Comment: @lol not without a copy of buffer as far as I know, but copy would kill any efficiency there was

Comment: Yo, I'm back. I found another way to do this. I'm not sure how it compares to Oleg's method, but here it is -

Comment: FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Create);
                fileStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, data);
                fileStream.Close();